# Проблема с массивами в Java

Tags: java

Возникла проблема при решении [задачи на CodeAbbey](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/sort-with-indexes--ru). Программа должна отсортировать массив и вывести для каждого элемента его порядковый номер в исходном массиве. Но в 10 строке она сортирует также и исходный массив, чего делать не должна. Из-за чего это, и как можно решить проблему?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int num = in.nextInt();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = fillArray(num);
        int[] sortedArr = bubbleSort(arr); // Сортирует исходный массив

        checkIndexes(sortedArr, arr);
    }

    static void checkIndexes(int[] sortedArr, int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < num; k++) {
                if (sortedArr[i] == arr[k]) {
                    System.out.print((k + 1) + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static int[] bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
        while (true) {
            int swaps = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
                if (arr[i] >= arr[i + 1]) {
                    int buff = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = buff;
                    swaps++;
                }
            }
            if (swaps == 0) break;
        }
        return arr;
    }

    static int[] fillArray(int num) {
        int[] arr = new int[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Так работает java  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  можете в `bubbleSort` входящий параметр обозвать `inputArr` а в самом начале метода, перед циклом,  написать `int[] arr = inputArr.clone();` или `int[] arr = Arrays.copyOf(inputArr, inputArr.length);` тогда все сработает ........ мне честно лень переводить статью на эту тему с enSO.  можете посмотреть сами http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757841/are-arrays-passed-by-value-or-passed-by-reference-in-java  ........ может позже напишет кто почему так

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [спецификации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) чётко указано,

> что переменная типа массив содержит ссылку на объект. Объявление переменной типа массив не создаёт объект или выделяет пространство для компонентов массива. Оно создаёт только саму переменную, которая может содержать ссылку на массив.
>
> A variable of array type holds a reference to an object. Declaring a variable of array type does not create an array object or allocate any space for array components. It creates only the variable itself, which can contain a reference to an array.

Таким образом, `int[] fillArray(int num)` возвращает ссылку на массив. Значение этой ссылки присваивается `int[] arr = fillArray(num)` переменной `arr`, a затем значение этой ссылки используется вызове метода `bubbleSort(arr)`.  То есть `bubbleSort` будет обращаться по этой ссылке к массиву, который был создан методом `fillArray`.

Для решения проблемы можно передать ссылку на копию массива. Например, `int[] sortedArr = bubbleSort(Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length))`. `Arrays.copyOf` создаст новый массив и 'bubbleSort' будет работать с ссылкой уже на этот новый массив.